# Best Repositories/DAOs for inherited entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inheritance

In my Hibernate+Spring project I've got several entities quite similar; that's why I'm using inheritance type: `Table Per Class`. The thing is similar to this

```
class CommonEntity {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String description;

  // Constructors & Setters & Getters
}

class InheritedClass1 extends CommonEntity {
  private boolean active;

  // Constructors & Setters & Getters
}

class InheritedClass2 extends CommonEntity {

}
```

As I'm using XML mapping, the mapping for the 1st inherited class contains both CommonEntity and InheritedClass1 fields/columns.

Everything's fine so far.

Here the question is, **what would be the best way to implement Repositories/DAOs for the inherited entities?** As they will contain common fields (for instance, probably it would end up in implementing a `findByName` DAO method).

My main point is to avoid implement the same `findByName` for all inherited class as the only difference would be the name of the `Named Query` (i.e. `InheritedClass1_FindByName` and `InheritedClass2FindByName`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics to make a single DAO method that would work for any class which extends your CommonEntity like this:

```
public <T extends CommonEntity > T getByName(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz, "named");
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("named.name", name));
    return (T)crit.uniqueResult();
}
```

Obviously if name is not unique you would need to call crit.list() rather than uniqueResult()

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about this possibility but I'm not really convinced... The problem I'm facing is likely very common so I guess there's a better solution for this...
I also have to say that the main purpose of my project is to learn. This is a personal "big" project to learn Spring & Hibernate. What that means? The more I learn the better :)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to get lots of generic dao functionality without writing much code then you should look at the [spring-data](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) project which allows you to create interfaces for daos which are automatically implemented for you. There are lots of ways to approach generic dao methods so it would largely depend on your data model and the ways you need to access your data as to which way is best.

Comment: This is a very interesting project (spring-data). I didn't hear about it! Thanks!
It seems it's based on JPA (which mostly implies the usage of Annotiations. I am using XML mapping for Hibernate though. Would that be a problem?

Comment: I have never tried it with XML mapping since I find the annotations far more user friendly and all the examples use annotations so sorry I can't help you with that

Comment: No problem! I'll give it a try anyway! I'll let you know!